# Parse: How to set a pointer in Android?

Tags: java, android, pointers, parse-platform

In my current class, say A, I have a column which is a pointer to another class, say B. Can anyone please let me know how I can set a value for this column in Android?

I have tried fetching the required row from class B as a ParseObject, and doing a:

```
classAObject.put("column_name",classBParseObject);
```

But, this is just creating an empty row in my class A, with no pointers. Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, there. What is the use of the pointer to class B? :)

Comment: This is like a foreign key. This column points to a particular row of class B, based on the primary key.

Comment: Okay great. So in your Android code (forget Parse for now), how do you store this key for B?

Comment: I am querying the required row from Parse using a String key in Android.

Comment: Have you tried using the `saveInBackground()` method of Parse to see if it fits your need? Honestly, I have no idea what you are trying to do. :)

Comment: Okay, let me be more clear. I have 2 classes (or tables) in Parse - Course, Student. In the Student table, there is a column called CourseId which is a pointer to the CourseId column of the Course table. I need to store the courseId for 'Computer Science' as a pointer to my current student. So, what I'm doing is:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have the objectID of the course ID for Computer Science, then you need to save using the createWithoutData method.  So let's recap:  You have a Student table with a column called CourseId - that is a pointer to the Course table, not the CourseId column of the Course table.  You can't point to a column, you point to a table.

So when you create a new Student object, you need to save a pointer into the CourseId column for Computer Science.  Let's say the objectID of the Computer Science object in your Course table is "xyz123".  You would do the following:

```
ParseObject student = new ParseObject("Student");
student.put("CourseId", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Course", "xyz123") );
//...set other values for the student object
student.saveInBackground();
```

The Parse docs has what you need and more - check out the section on relational data:
https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers

Comment: I have something additional to ask on the same topic, how can someone set the pointer to it's default of (undefined) or null?

Comment: Thanks a lot, was googling for hours.

Comment: @user2163298  how can i do if i m saving Users in User table intead of object as i have to  save ppointer of User table in installation table using parse.com in android

Comment: Now how do I retrieve this data?

Answer (score 5):

If it is a custom class then use the following code (Eg : "AnotherClass" is a custom class)

```
classAObject.put("column_name", ParseObject.createWithoutData("AnotherClass", "abc123"));
```

or if it is Parse Class like User, Installations etc, use like this,

```
classAObject.put("column_name", ParseObject.createWithoutData(ParseUser.class, "abc123"));
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was pulling my hair out trying to find out how to get a pointer to my Installation table. Second option was the key!

Comment: You are Amazing Thankyou So Much

Comment: You can also do Parse.User.createWithoutData(userObject.objectId)