# Can't set user objectId to parse pointer field

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform, objectid

For a new project I was running some tests. For now I have a function in which I am trying to save an object to the parse.com framework and all went well untill I added a user pointer object. The pointer line seems to block my code when I use the current user's objectId as a value for it. Using a random word of the user's email adres however does work. I added my code below.

```
   // Create a data object and store it online.
   public void createDataObject(){
        ParseObject object = new ParseObject("TestData");
        object.put("action", "trial");
        object.put("value", "succes?");
        object.put("name", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        String pointer = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        Log.i(TAG, pointer);
        object.put("pointer", ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", pointer));
        object.saveEventually();
    }
```

I hope anyone can help me figure it out, help is greatly appreciated!

Update: The problem is not my pointer command but it's the fact I use saveEventually(); If I use saveInBackground it just works but I want to use saveEventually because of possible lost network connection. Does anyone have a clue what could be the problem?

Update 2: Finally decided to delete the app and the installationId of the Parse data browser. Upon reinstalling the app everything started working like it should. I probably had a bad piece of code that got stuck with my installation Id. I hope others with the same problem reach this post fast and don't spend several days searching for an answer!

Update 3: There was a certain function that tried to find a user based on a pointer with the app user's object ID which made the app crash once and than totally unusable. I marked the first answer as the correct answer since it solved my original question but just fyi.. there was more going on than I expected at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
public void createDataObject(){
        ParseObject object = new ParseObject("TestData");
        object.put("action", "trial");
        object.put("value", "succes?");
        object.put("name", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        object.put("pointer", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        object.saveEventually();
    }
```

No need to get the object ID to set the current User.

Edit:
You can also refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28403968/2571060 to set pointer

Comment: I tried doing it the way you suggested before I got to the point of answering and I tried it again today but as soon as I give it a go my memory spikes and the app crashes. I do not understand why this happens, but it gives me a stackoverflow and a lot of com.parse.*.isdirty errors..

What is strange however. If I use ParseUser.getCurrentUser() in a Log.i entry, it does write the User's Object Id to the log. I checked and it is the correct objectId corresponding to my user.

Comment: It may be because of many reasons. Can you provide those error logs.

Comment: Try saveEventually with a callback and see crash is happening before saving or after saving. Are you trying to save only one object or many are there.?

Comment: I will try in a bit. I am only saving one object. The on create rubs the functioning I posted above if a user is logged in. The problem wasn't here until 2 days ago. I'll report back on the callback!

Comment: I wrote a save callback and it does not return. However when I comment the line which sets the pointer, it does return. Strange things is, changing saveEventually to saveInBackground does work with the pointer object uncommented and does return... I really don't know what to do now?

Comment: I seem to have finally found the solution. I decided to delete the app (again) and also delete the installationId from the parse data browser. I reinstalled it and now everything seems to work just fine.. Thanks for helping anyway, hope I didn't waste too much of your time!

Comment: @RajeshHegde  can u come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78275/parse-com i have to save user object id in installation pointer field but i m failed to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the iOS SDK. Are you using 'automatic user creation' ? Cause in that case, ParseUser.getCurrentUser() returns a User object whose objectId is null. According the documentation, it is null until the user or any object related to it is saved. But in my experience, it is not the case, I had to save the user first or I would get an error like 'User can only be created during signUp' or something like this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not using automatic user creation. I wrote a custom signup and login script to handle users.